# How to add List of figures and list of tables into Contents page

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to add the list of tables and list of figures into the Contents table and change their page numbering into Arabic. My template.cls code is below:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} \ProvidesClass{template}

\RequirePackage{setspace}

\LoadClass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\oddsidemargin 14.6truemm \evensidemargin 0truemm
\marginparwidth 40pt \marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin 0truemm \headsep 10truemm
\textheight 224truemm \textwidth 145truemm

\brokenpenalty=10000

\onehalfspacing

\def\degreetitle#1{\gdef\@degreetitle{#1}}
\def\rpttype#1{\gdef\@rpttype{#1}}

\def\principaladviser#1{\gdef\@principaladviser{#1}}
\def\advis@r{Advisor} % default spelling---we are English!
\def\principaladvisor#1{\gdef\@principaladviser{#1}\gdef\advis@r{Advisor}}
\def\firstreader#1{\gdef\@firstreader{#1}}
\def\secondreader#1{\gdef\@secondreader{#1}}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} 
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{School of Computing}
\def\@principaladviser{}\def\@firstreader{}\def\@secondreader{}
\def\@submitdate{\ifcase\the\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\the\year}

\newif\ifcopyright \newif\iffigurespage \newif\iftablespage \newif\ifalgorithmspage \newif\ifsigpage \copyrightfalse \figurespagetrue \tablespagetrue \algorithmspagefalse  \sigpagefalse

\def\titlep{%
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \null\vskip1in%
        \begin{center}
                \large\sc\expandafter{\@title}\\
        \vskip 0.25in
                {\Large \@author}
        \vskip 0.45in
        \includegraphics[height=40mm]{rgulogo}
        \vfill
        \vskip 0.25in
        \end{center}
        \begin{center}
                \sc A report submitted as part of the requirements for the degree\\ of
                \@degreetitle
 \\at the School of Computing \\Robert Gordon University\\ Aberdeen, Scotland

        \end{center}
        \vfill
        \vskip 0.5in
        \begin{center}
                \@submitdate
        \end{center}
        \vfill
        \begin{center}
                \normalfont
                Supervisor \@principaladviser\\
        \end{center}\vskip.5in\newpage}

\def\declpage{%
\prefacesection{Declaration}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{4.5in}
              \parindent=0pt
                I confirm that the work contained in this \@rpttype \space project report has been composed solely by myself and has not been accepted in any previous application for a degree. All sources of information have been specifically acknowledged and all verbatim extracts are distinguished by quotation marks.
                \par
                \vskip 2in
                 Signed ............................................ \hspace{0.5 in} Date ......................\\
                 \hspace*{0.4 in} \@author 
                 \par
        \end{minipage}%
        \end{center}%
        \vfill}

\def\beforeabstract{
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \pagestyle{plain}
        \titlep
        \ifsigpage\signaturepage\fi


\def\afterabstract{
%%        \newpage
       % \declpage

\tableofcontents
        \newpage
        \iftablespage
                \addvspace{10pt}
                \listoftables
                \newpage
        \fi
        \iffigurespage
                \addvspace{10pt}
                \listoffigures
                \newpage
        \fi
    \ifalgorithmspage
                \addvspace{10pt}
                \listofalgorithms
                \newpage
        \fi}

        }


\def\prefacesection#1{%
        \chapter*{#1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\def\afterpreface{\newpage
        \pagestyle{plain}}

\pagestyle{plain}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth
  {\uppercase{\bibname}}{\uppercase{\bibname}}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
  \list
  {\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}{\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \def\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}}%
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus.33em minus.07em}%
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=\@m}

\def\endthebibliography{%
  \def\@noitemerr{\@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
```

and the .Tex code

```
\documentclass{template}
\usepackage{graphicx,parskip,appendix,float}
\usepackage[ruled] {algorithm2e}
\usepackage{url,amsmath,amssymb,fancybox,listings,pdfpages,caption,multicol,datetime,rotating, booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,pdffitwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=none,
    backref,
    natbib,
    hyperref
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}


%NOTE: The hyperref usepackage should be the last \usepackage!!
%NOTE: When pagebackref=true an error will appear at the end of compiling. press `q' to ignore
%NOTE: Referencing Algorithms does not work if this usepackage is before the hyperref include.!!
%NOTE: This is a comment, ignored when the document is compiled
%NOTE: The following document configuration settings generally do not need to be modified
%NOTE: More packages may need to be added to provide additional functionality

\hypersetup{
    pdftitle    = {Report Title},
    pdfauthor   = {Author Name},
    pdfsubject  = {Subject Area},
    pdfkeywords = {Comma separated list of keywords},
    colorlinks  = true, anchorcolor = blue, filecolor = blue, urlcolor = blue,
    linkcolor   = blue,    %NOTE: change (blue) to (colIdentifier) to have links within the document in Black
    citecolor   = blue,    %NOTE: change (blue) to (colIdentifier) to have citation links within the document in Black
}

\definecolor{colBackGrnd}{rgb}{1,1,0.8}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colWhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\newcommand{\MyHookSign}{\hbox{\ensuremath\hookleftarrow}}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Proposition}[Theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Proof}[Theorem]{Proof}
\newtheorem{Remark}[Theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{Claim}[Theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{Example}[Theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{Definition}[Theorem]{Definition}

%NOTE: Setup for including program listings
\lstset{%
    float=H,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
    keywordstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    stringstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
    commentstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=single,
    extendedchars=true, %
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left, %
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,
    prebreak={\space\MyHookSign},
    language=Java,
    backgroundcolor=\color{colBackGrnd},
    breakautoindent=true, %
    captionpos=b%
} %\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=\color{colIdentifier}}

\sloppy %NOTE: To ensure the Right Hand Margin is used (Especially for long URLS)
%NOTE: END of the document configuration settings

\begin{document}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.png,.gif,.pdf}
%NOTE: When inserting Figures if the extension of the graphic file is not provided LaTeX will automatically search
% for the extensions declared above, in the order declared.

\title{\huge{Report Title}}
\author{Author Full Name}
\degreetitle{Degree Title} % Replace with appropriate degree
\rpttype{MSc}    % Replace MSc with BSc for Honours Degree Year projects.
\principaladviser{Dr. XXX XXX}

\include{intro/abstract}
\listofalgorithms   %NOTE: Will generate a list of Algorithms in the Table of Contents Section
%\lstlistoflistings  %NOTE: Will generate a list of Program Listings in the Table of Contents Section

%NOTE: Include the relative reference for each chapter to be included
% dividing the thesis file structure into a number of directories aids development
% format: directoryName/filename (the .tex extension is not required for the filename)


\include{intro/introduction}
\include{Lit/Literature review}
\include{design/design}
\include{impl/implementation}
\include{conclude/conclude}


\footnotesize  %NOTE: reduced the size of the text for the bibliography
%NOTE: set the style for the bibliography and display the references used within the document
\printbibliography
\normalsize
\appendix
\include{appendix/appendix}
\end{document} %NOTE: END of document, nothing after this point
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code using this class resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch I have updated the post to include the TeX file code.

Comment: The currently shown code does neither show a table of contents nor a list of figures nor a list of tables. Please note, that a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) always should show the problem *without the need to guess or change anything*. Otherwise it is mostly useless and it would be hard or even impossible to help. But maybe …

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, but i am using a template on overleaf
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/rgu-thesis-template-2023/jjzgwddwzmqm